# https://git.heroku.com/whatsapp-clone5.git [remote rejected] main(pre-recei) failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/whatsapp-clone5.git'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku

hello I'm trying to build my project for Heroku
I use React.js, Node.js and MongoDB
when I write those commands :

```
heroku login
git init
heroku git:remote -a whatsapp-clone5
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku main
```

This error appears to me

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is likely not recognising the type of application you are pushing. Output of `$ heroku logs` would help diagnose the issue.

[You might need to manually configure the buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)